# Как в GeoDjango правильно посчитать площадь по двум точкам?

Tags: python-3.x, django, gps, postgis

Даны две точки по диагонали : (top_left_longitude, top_left_latitude), (bottom_right_longitude, bottom_right_latitude).

Необходимо посчитать площадь в GeoDjango. Делаю так:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon

polygon = Polygon(
    (
        (top_left_longitude, top_left_latitude),
        (top_left_longitude, bottom_right_latitude),
        (bottom_right_longitude, bottom_right_latitude),
        (bottom_right_longitude, top_left_latitude),
        (top_left_longitude, top_left_latitude)
    ),
    srid=4236
)

polygon.transform(ct=28432, clone=False)
area = polygon.area / 1000000
```

Но площадь получается не равна расчетной. Что не так делаю, не могу понять?

Comment: еще актуально? на каких данных неправильно считает площадь?

Comment: Уже не актуально, решил немного по-другому. Рассчитывал по 2м точкам в онлайн сервисе, уже точно не скажу каком